# Are there multiple ways to set bean value and save them into database using PersistentObject

Tags: java, mysql

I am using SQL PreparedStatement to store values in DB using PersistentObject to store state of the object using boolean flags, is there any way to store in multiple tables at once?

I have used PreparedStatement.executeUpdate().

```
psmt = this.buildSQL(persistent, psmt, databaseAccess);
result=psmt.executeUpdate();
if (persistent.isNew())
    persistent.setNewFlag(false);
if (result == 0)
    return;
```

Comment: Is your question like you want to store one data in two tables at one shot?

Comment: Yes, one data in two tables at one shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry with that you can not achieve insert two query in one shot.

But you can do with below posted code which may helps you to understand more about insert data in multiple table.

```
try (Connection connection = **strong text**DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb", "root", "password")) {

try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO PUBLISHER (CODE, PUBLISHER_NAME) VALUES (?, ?)")) {
    stmt.setString(1, book.getPublisher().getCode());   
    stmt.setString(2, book.getPublisher().getName());           
    stmt.executeUpdate();
}
// stmt is auto closed here, even if SQLException is thrown

try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO BOOK (ISBN, BOOK_NAME, PUBLISHER_CODE) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    stmt.setString(1, book.getIsbn());  
    stmt.setString(2, book.getName());
    stmt.setString(3, book.getPublisher().getCode());
    stmt.executeUpdate();
}
// stmt is auto closed here, even if SQLException is thrown
}// connection is auto closed here, even if SQLException is thrown
```